# I'm currently new to programming. passing argument 1 of 'scanf' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion], is my error

Tags: c, warnings

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{   
    int a = scanf(printf("Enter your first no."));
    int b = scanf(printf("Enter your second no."));
    int c = a + b;
    printf( "your sum is :  %d ", c );
    
    return(0);
}
```

I tried to modify the code a few times but it did not work.

Comment: You seem to have skipped some of the very early chapters of your beginners material. The `scanf` function does not work as you guess it does.

Comment: It is better to follow a book or tutorial than to guess.

Comment: How did you try to modify your code? Did you look into the specification of the functions you are using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the scanf() function in the wrong way. Inside the bracest of the scanf() function, you have control string, starting and ending with ", and which have to contains one or more format specifiers. Each format specifier is coresponding to certain data type. Check what is "format specifier", and also check what is the format specifier for each data type. It is a good tip to leave 1 empty position before every format specifier. If you use multiple format specifiers - then you just separate them with 1 empty space.

After the control string, you place a comma sign ",", and after that the address of a variable. This you do, when you put the sign "&", and the name of the variable. Have in mind that the format specifier, must coresponds to the data type, to which the variable belongs.

So, making your code to work, you have to edit it like that:

```
#include<stdio.h>
/*#include<string.h> - You don't need this header file*/

int main()
{   
    int a, b; //Defining multiple variables of same type.
    printf("Enter value for a: ");
    scanf(" %i", &a);//Assigning value to a;
    printf("Enter value for b: ");
    scanf(" %i", &b);//Assigning value to b;

    printf("Your sum is: %i", (a+b));//You don't need third variable, to store the sum.

    return(0);
}
```

Pro-tip: There is difference when you are using "%d" and "%i" format specifiers for input purposes (i.e. "scanf()"). If you use "%d" - then you must enter values only in decimal numeral system (so-called "base 10"). If you use "%i" - then you can enter integer values in octal, decimal or hexadecimal numeral systems.